# JS game Crowns and Anchors: error in outcome

Tags: javascript, iteration, addition

I'm having trouble understanding the outcome of a game I have developed with the help of the book 'Learning JavaScript' by Ethan Brown.

Here is the code:

```
//helper functions for randomizing
function rand(x,y){
  return x + Math.floor((y-x+1)*Math.random());
}

function getFace(){ return ['crown','heart','spade','club','diamond','anchor'][rand(0,5)]; }

//the game
function crownsAndAnchors(){
  console.log('Let\'s play Crowns and Anchors!');
  let rounds = 0;
  let funds = 50;
  while( funds > 1 && funds < 100 ){
    rounds ++;
    console.log(`Round: ${rounds}`);
    let totalBet = 7;
    let bets = { crown: 0, heart: 0, spade:0, club:0, diamond:0, anchor:0 };
    if (totalBet == 7){
      totalBet = funds;
      console.log('You pulled out 7p, your lucky number! Bet all on heart');
      bets.heart = totalBet;
    }else{
       //distribute totalBet randomly
    }
    funds = funds - totalBet;
    console.log('\tBets: ' + Object.keys(bets).map(face => `${face} ${bets[face]}p`).join(' || ') + `  (total: ${totalBet} pence)`);
    const hand = [];
     // roll the dice
    console.log("_______________rolling the dice ____________")
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      hand.push(getFace());
    }
    console.log(`\tHand: ${hand.join(', ')}`);
    //check for winnings
    let wins = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < hand.length; i++) {
      let face = hand[i];
      if (bets[face] > 0) wins = wins + bets[face];
    }
    funds = funds + wins;
    console.log(`\tWinnings: ${wins}`);
  }
  console.log(`\nEnding Funds: ${funds}`);
}

crownsAndAnchors();
```

I have hard-coded variable `totalBet` to be 7 to easily monitor final outcome. For example, if two out of three die outcomes are `heart` than the Ending Funds should be `150`, correct?

However, when I run the code (Node `v7.6.0`) this is what I am returned:

```
Let's play Crowns and Anchors!

Round: 1
You pulled out 7p, your lucky number! Bet all on heart
        Bets: crown: 0p || heart: 50p || spade: 0p || club: 0p || diamond: 0p || anchor: 0p  (total: 50 pence)
_______________rolling the dice ____________
        Hand: heart, heart, club
        Winnings: 100

Ending funds: 100
```

I know I'm somehow updating `funds` incorrectly I just cannot figure out why.

Thank you so much in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

The line 
funds = funds - totalBet; 
is setting funds to 0, then later you get two wins of 50 added to it to give you 100.

If you eliminate that line where funds = funds - totalBet, then you get the 150 you are expecting.

Or move that line to after the dice roll and only execute it if you did not win anything.

Comment: Good eye, Larry! I went ahead and removed that line and added to the bottom of the _//check for winnings_ `for loop` block statement
`if (!wins) { funds = funds - totalBet; } `

It seems to be working according to statistical probability, now! Thank you